# Direct product $\mathbb Z_p \times A$ and $\mathbb Z_p \times B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $\mathbb Z_p \times A \simeq \mathbb Z_p \times B$, where $p$ is prime.
Is it true, that $A \simeq B$?

Comment: If $A,B$ are abelian, the answer is yes. See Gone's answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/cancellation-of-direct-products

Comment: Thank you, it is very interesting. But it is not use, that $p$ is prime.

Comment: @Alex-mosk, so is there any restriction about $A,B$ at all? It would be good to know the context of your question.

Comment: This is true with no assumptions on $A, B$. See the link.