# If two internal products are isomorphic and one of each are isomorphic then the others are isomorphic

Tags: group-isomorphism

I want to show that for abelian finite group $A$, $A = G \oplus H \simeq G' \oplus H'$ and $G \simeq G'$ then $H \simeq H'$. I found the proof : I defined $K=G\cap H'$ and $K' = G' \cap H$, and I showed that if $K$ or $K' $ is zero group then it is proved hence assumed $K$ and $K'$ nonzero. Now I want to use induction on $|G|$, so I need to prove $H \oplus G/K \oplus G'/K'$ is isomorphic to $H' \oplus G/K \oplus G'/K'$. Now by some calculation I found that I need to prove only $H'/K \oplus G' \oplus G'/K' \simeq H/K' \oplus G \oplus G/K$. And I stuck. Since $G$ is isomorphic to $G'$ the only left one is other two terms aand i'm guessing it's simple too, but I'm not sure how to prove it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This property is called "cancellation", and it does hold for all finite groups. For a short and nice proof, see [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/hirshon/cancel/cancel.pdf).

For finitely generated abelian groups, the cancellation property just follows
by the Fundamental Theorem of  Abelian Groups. In general cancellation may not hold. For more details see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/cancellation-of-direct-products), and the links given there.

Comment: I can't understand this part : B/F * D/K = B1/K * D1/F. What isomorphism theorem used in this part? I guess the most similar one is 3rd - G/K / H/K = G/H, but I can't go further.